# How to save object with a Set using Spring CrudRepository

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Is there any way to save an object with a `Set` using Spring `CrudRrepository`?
For example I have the objects `Artist` and `Album`.
`Artist` has a list(Set) of `Album` (Albums).
I would to when I save an `Artist` with all fields populate and  the list of Albums also populate save this list as well just calling `artistRepository.save` method.
Or I need before save only `Artist` using `artistRepository` and after, take the `artistId` and save the Albums?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the option “Cascade.persist” over the one to many relation between Artist and Albums, it will persist (save) new Albums while creating new Artist. Also read about other Cascade options